# slack bot respond to messages with a mention

Tags: python-2.7, slack-api

I have a simple slack bot that can respond to messages that start with a specific string. What I would prefer is that the bot only responds to messages that have a mention of the bot. I'm using `slackclient` and getting messages via:

```
new_evts = sc.rtm_read()
```

I can see the my client_id in the message but searching message stings doesn't seem to be the right approach.

```
u'text': u'<@U0TP3B7HU>: test message'
```

There has to be a more slack-onic way of handling messages with mentions. What am I missing in the Slack API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an slack app reply to the person who mentioned me in a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146503/can-an-slack-app-reply-to-the-person-who-mentioned-me-in-a-channel)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the Slack documentation for the message event](https://api.slack.com/events/message) and taking a look at actual events (as you have), there doesn't appear to be any "better" way to detect mentions in a message. I believe the approach of searching the text of the message is the only option. For example, [that's what botkit does](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/563f976a6b4c675712e5ae8a03689cf7e420149e/lib/SlackBot.js#L484).

Answer (score 0):

I found a library that provides a way to respond to mentions. [This](https://github.com/lins05/slackbot) library provides a mechanism to designate a function to be called when a message is directed at a specific user.

`@respond_to('github', re.IGNORECASE)
def github():
    ...`

I really didn't like the regular expression code and having to search every posted. This is a simpler way to handle responding to DMs or @references in messages.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68148014/7471516), you can subscribe to an 'app_mention' event for your bot.**

https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention