# How do I receive only the messages that are direct messages to my bot user?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have successfully setup my slack bot app, have enabled events etc. I want to receive any direct messages that the members of my slack team send to my bot. For this, I have only enabled **Bot Events** and **No Team Events** like below

[image]

However, I do not get any event on my webhook on this setting.

If I enable `message.im` event under Team Events, then I start getting events. But then, I get every message that the user (who has installed the app) sends to any other user in the team.

How do I get only the messages that are sent to my bot user?

### Update 1

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775061/receive-message-from-slack-bot?rq=1) I created a private channel with the bot user. Even then, the messages in the private channel do not arrive in my webhook with the above event subscriptions.

### Update 2

After reinstalling the app, it seems to be working fine. I have only used it for few minutes after the reinstall so far. I will keep posting here how it goes. It would still be interesting to know what went wrong where.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal behavior that your script receives all messages (for every channel your bot is a member of), not only the messages sent directly to your bot. At this time you can not filter further in the event configuration. So you need to filter out any unwanted message in your script handling the event.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416696/receiving-to-many-requests-in-my-bot-user-from-slack) answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link. However, in my case, the bot was getting the conversations from the channels that the bot was not part of. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app helped.