# GroupMe, Telegram & Slack channel on Bot Framework responds to every message

Tags: botframework, telegram, slack-api, groupme

Is there an easy configuration way of only receiving messages when the bot is mentioned in Group chats?

I want it to respond to 1on1 messages without needing a mention as well.

Is there an easy way to handle this?

So far, I've noticed that this happens on GroupMe, Telegram, and Slack.

This seems specific to the Microsoft Bot Framework. I feel like this should be configurable... Here's the entirety of my code on github: https://github.com/mtntop/mtnbot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving too many requests in my Bot user from slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416696/receiving-too-many-requests-in-my-bot-user-from-slack)

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't see that one before. That question doesn't really answer it for me. I'm looking for something more related to the Bot Framework.

Comment: how would the bot know you are talking to it without the mention? This doesn't seem possible to me unless I am missing something.  By 1on1 do you mean private chat or group chat messages directed to the bot?

Comment: 1on1 I mean private chat.

What I would like is:
In a PM with the Bot, you don't need to @ mention it
In a GroupChat that the Bot is in, I'd like the Bot to only respond when it is @ mentioned

Comment: For PMs I think it might be possible by using the conversationId, I haven't yet played with the telegram or GroupMe but this might be the way to go. From my experiences in Slack you shouldn't need to @mention it in a 1-on-1 conversation, this might be a bug. This method of using the conversationId could be dependent on # of members in the conversation...

Comment: You're right, I don't need to @ mention it in a 1-on-1 conversation. But, the problem is... in a Group chat, the bot ends up responding to every single message that comes in. I want it to only respond when it's mentioned in Group chats. When in 1-on-1 I don't want the requirement of an @ mention